# How to add a linestring/polyline to a custom MapBox template with GeoJSON

Tags: jquery, foursquare, leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I am currently working on modifying the store locator template from MapBox:
https://github.com/mapbox/foursquare-store-locator
https://www.mapbox.com/blog/foursquare-store-locator/

The problem is in adding a linestring/polyline to this modified framework.

For example, I am not able to add a new map layer with the linestring GeoJSON data using this format:

```
L.map('map').
```

I can get the linestring to work with leafllet.js:

---

http://jsfiddle.net/xpancom/hUy5g/16/

---

...but this utilizes the "L." from leaflet.js and doesn't work in the modified MapBox template.

```
L.geoJson(myLine1, {style: myStyle}).addTo(map);
```

The problem is the modified store locator app from MapBox doesn't appear to implement this same interface.

Here is my current code that attempts to add the layer that has the linestrings:

```
foursquare.lines = function() {

  var lines = { 'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': []
    };

lines.features.push({
            type: 'Feature',
           // id: venue.id,
            geometry: {
                type: 'LineString',
                coordinates: [[
            60.317769,
            24.929009
          ],
          [
            24.9292486208828,
            60.1681323558666
          ],
          [
            24.951764345169067,
            60.168932342858554
          ],
          [
            24.93321418762207,
            60.16911913731421
          ],
          [
            24.952929,
            60.167312
          ],
          [
            24.944114685058594,
            60.170111798603266
          ],
          [
            24.94499444961548,
            60.171435300334004
          ]]
            },
            properties: {}

        }); //push

//console.log(lines);

if (MM_map.lineLayer) {
        MM_map.lineLayer.geojson(lines);
        alert("hi");
    } else {
        MM_map.lineLayer = mmg().geojson(lines);
        //alert("hello");
        console.log(lines);
    }

 MM_map.addLayer(MM_map.lineLayer);

  }; //foursquare.lines
```

The layer gets added as an empty div but the geojson and the lines object don't get processed and don't show.

When I run console.log(lines) I get all the geojson data correctly it just doesn't get added using this line:

```
mmg().geojson(lines)
```

I really appreaciate any help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The foursquare store locator example is based on MapBox.js v0.6.7, whereas you're trying to use code from v1.x and beyond. You'll either need to consult the v0.6.7 docs, or start from a different starting point, which is what I'd recommend - see [the MapBox.js examples](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/) for instance.

Comment: Cool thanks for your response. I did find this page https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/line-marker/ but here's the problem.... How can attach this code to the foursquare.js function here https://github.com/mapbox/foursquare-store-locator/blob/gh-pages/foursquare.js

Comment: That's a v1.x example: I'd recommend you either start from an example and rebuild the site from scratch, or use v0.6.7 examples and APIs only.

Comment: could you let me know what happened to the mapbox editor? When I try to access this URL https://tiles.mapbox.com/mitchflorida/edit/g6hfd6aj#15/60.1692/24.9554 it redirects me to https://www.mapbox.com/#15/60.1692/24.9554 and I do not see how to add a layer... Can you still add a custom TileMill layer to mapbox? Thanks!